# What is custom function in google spreadsheet to find the user by the user email in the user tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Thanks in advance for helping
What is custom function in google spreadsheet  to find the user by the user email in the user tab ?

Please send me whole step for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`var viewers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getViewers();`

returns an array of viewer emails

`if ( viewers.indexof('example@gmail.com') >= 0 ) {
   // do something
}`

Comment: Please can you tell me in details how i can make it. I means I wantto make custom function in google spreadsheet to find the user by the user email in the user tab

Comment: @user3488444 I don't believe it's possible to build a "custom function" (by custom I mean a function that is usable as the natives spreadsheet functions - right in the cells) read the permission chapter of the google doc: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions?hl=fr